# How to use SSL when using Apache.NMS.AMQP?

Tags: .net, ssl, amqp, activemq-artemis, nms

Im currently trying to implement support for AMQP into a .Net library. However, I cant quite figure out which schema to use when running AMQP and SSL. From Googling it I see that there are two schemas that are suggested from time to time: `amqps://` and `amqp+ssl://`. However, looking at the Apache.NMS implementation of the `NMSConnectionFactory`, not any of those two schemas would match against the [connectionfactory mappings](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-api/blob/main/src/nms-api/NMSConnectionFactory.cs).

The map is located at line 58-77, and it's used at line 308.
As you might notice neither `amqps` nor `amqp+ssl` are listed in the mapping-object. So how would one use SSL and AMQP while using Apache.NMS?

Comment: fyi.. there is a third option of specifying amqp and ssl that I have seen.. amqp:ssl:// (which still doesnt match any of the mappings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth noting that the [AMQP implementation for NMS](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-amqp) is built on top of [AMQP.NET Lite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite). The [URL configuration documentation](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-amqp/blob/main/docs/configuration.md) states:

> The basic format of the clients Connection URI is as follows:
>
> ```
> amqp[s]://hostname:port[?option=value[&option2=value...]]
> ```
>
> Where the `amqps` and scheme is specified to use SSL/TLS.

A simple example is available [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-amqp/blob/main/src/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cs). Notice that the example uses the `NmsConnectionFactory` implementation from `Apache.NMS.AMQP` and *not* the one from `Apache.NMS`. I recommend you do the same.

`Apache.NMS` is, after all, an **API**. It really shouldn't have its own implementation of `NmsConnectionFactory` as it needs to be updated every time a new implementation is created. In my opinion this is a backwards design which is confusing for users.

Comment: Yes, Im aware of that.. but that makes it all even more confusing.. since Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionFactory only includes a mapping for amqp scheme and not for amqps.. so I guess if my Uri would be specified as amqps://localhost, then Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionFactory would have no idea of how to map that to the correct ConnectionFactory.  Or am I misstaken?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot! I fully agree with that its strange to implement the factory pattern in the way Apache.NMS does it.. or at least it should cover all possible scenarios if to be used.. guess however I could create my own factory if so needed..

Comment: Sort of OT question.. but since you seem to "know your way around" in the domain of ActiveMQ :).. what would be the correct Uri for connecting using OpenWire? I have seen a sample where activemq:tcp://localhost:port is used.. but to me that looks strange.. and more like a work around to comply with NMS, since that would match with the mapping for

Comment: The uri `activemq:tcp://localhost:port` does look strange, but it will work if you're using the `NmsConnectionFactory` implementation from `Apache.NMS`. However, I would recommend you using [`ConnectionFactory` from `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-openwire/blob/main/src/ConnectionFactory.cs) instead. That would allow you to use the more straight-forward `tcp://localhost:port`.